# How to write more than one mod-rewrite rule?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I always used the following rule to manage urls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./urlredirect.php
```

With this I could easily check with php which page the user was trying to access.

Now I got a site that requires https on all pages. Here is the basic solution to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

My problem now is that I cannot get both working simultaneously.
I know very little of mod-rewrite and regular expressions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apache docs:
HTTP to HTTPS
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

So you'd need the conditional, then the rule for each.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./urlredirect.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I cannot believe it worked, I literally had every line just in different order. Wouldn't have guessed order mattered. Thanks